# How to upload images in persistantStorage of Nodejs Application in Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, angular, image, kubernetes, upload

I have a nodejs application that has image upload functionality. Is it possible to store these images in persistantStorage of kuberernates. These images also need to be loaded and displayed in an angular application as well. Any tutorials link would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean ephemeral storage vs persistent storage?

Technically speaking, there is no limitation to storing on the ephemeral disk, however you don't want to because its transient and not designed to store dynamic data outside that needs to live past any restart.

Now on the flip side, if you are referring to a NAS another volume mounted and shared across all instances in the cluster, then yes you should be able to store to that mount as well, you would just need to have that drive mounted and a symlink created so your application can store to it.

Personally though, I lead toward s3 (or other object store solution) simply because it separates the need to mount additional drives, is fast and easy to use.